# Azure redirect to custom 404 page

Tags: azure, iis, web-config, http-status-code-404, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to configure a web app in Azure to redirect to an html page if the http status code is 404. This is a static html site in Azure.  I have added web.config and ApplicationHost.xdt files with these contents and it doesn't do anything:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" >
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="http://www.website.com/404/index.html" />
</httpErrors>
```

I've restarted the web app after making these changes and it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on your webconfig file, if change the path to **"/404/index.html"**, it will work correctly. Please have a try.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" >
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/404/index.html" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```